# How to customize a Jenkins job dsl method

Tags: jenkins

I want to customize the powerShell() method in jobDSL

a .groovy file with some job dsl defined jobs

```
def betterPowerShell(def cmd) {
    powerShell("$cmd; exit \$LastExitCode")
}
```

Since I am out of the

```
job {
  step {
  }
}
```

context this is not working...

Maybe I need something like...

```
def betterPowerShell(def cmd) {
    javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext.powerShell("$cmd; exit \$LastExitCode")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [Jenkins shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) which will allow you to (among other things) define custom Pipeline DSL steps in a repository you own.  See the ["Defining custom steps" section](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps) in that document.

Here's the example custom step from that document:

```
// vars/sayHello.groovy
def call(String name = 'human') {
    // Any valid steps can be called from this code, just like in other
    // Scripted Pipeline
    echo "Hello, ${name}."
}
```

Comment: I wanted to call powerShell() from the powershell jobDSL plugin. Will that work in this context?

Comment: Yes, you can call other Pipeline steps from your custom Pipeline step.  In fact most of the custom steps that I have written using this method call other Pipeline steps.

Comment: how do you load the shared library in a Job DSL seed then? https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/11833/how-do-i-load-a-jenkins-shared-library-in-a-jenkins-job-dsl-seed